# Is it OK to have only a single class labels in test data for prediction with one-class-svm?

Tags: svm, outliers, anomaly-detection, one-class, novelty-detection

I have a data which has only a single class, namely, `'0'`. There is no `'not 0'` class.

The one-class SVM model was trained on a `train` dataset containing only a single class `'0'`. I do not unnecessarily want to find a random `'not 0'` class to include in `test` dataset for prediction.

What will be the output of this approach?
How can we interpret the result?
What if the `specificity` is `0`? Is it normal or have `sensitivity` and `specificity` to be `0`?
In that case how do we plot ROC curve?

After training it only on `'0'` class, I tested it on only `'0'` class (unseen and unlabeled data), and the model still gave `'-1'` for a few samples. Why did not it give all `'1'`?

I will appreciate an example on an arbitrary data.

Comment: If you have only a single class, what is your goal in modeling or classifying?

Comment: @StephanKolassa My goal is to identify (classify) '0' class I have.

Comment: The one-class SVM model was trained on a ```train``` dataset containing only a single class ```'0'.``` Congratulations! You've trained a model that says 0 all the time!

Answer (score 1):

If your entire data only has the "0" class, then life is easy: just classify everything as "0". Any tool or method will do so, too. (If a method, upon seeing *only* "0" instances, classifies something as "[rhubarb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhubarb)", I would question its sanity.)

If you classify everything as "0", and everything *is* in fact "0", then every instance is a true positive. There are no false positives, true or false negatives. Sensitivity is $\frac{n}{n}=1$, specifity is undefined, $\frac{0}{0}$.

As to the ROC curve: there is no threshold to tune, the FPR is constant at zero, the TPR is constant at one, and your ROC curve degenerates to a point in the top left hand corner. AUROC is 1.

And to be honest, everything is maximally useless. If you already know everything is of just one class, why bother modeling?

Comment: So what is the correct way to make sense? I guess, train on '0' class, and test on '0' plus 'not 0' class? Can you present an example?

Comment: Do you know if there exist anomaly/novelty/outlier detection method which works directly on images and not on image descriptors?

Comment: By the way after training it only on '0' class,  I tested it on only '0' class (unseen and unlabeled data), and the model still gave '-1' for a few samples. Why did not it give all '1'?